# How do you define a v-slot in the Vue render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying my best to get it working, but I just can't find out how...

What I'm trying to do is to create a `v-text-field` with the `v-slot:prepend` within. In this `prepend` slot I want to show a short string, like 'Hi!'.

This is what I have so far:

```
new Vue({
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(
            'v-text-field',
            {
                scopedSlots: {
                    prepend: () => {
                        return createElement('span', 'Hi!')
                    }
                }
            },
            this.$slots.default
        );
    },
    components: {
        VTextField,
    },
    // add vuetify to make use of standard vuetify functionality
    vuetify,
}).$mount();
```

At the moment it just shows the `v-text-field` as it should do, just without the `prepend slot`...

Who can help me?